# Playn for Applications other than games

Tags: gwt, widget, playn

I was wondering has anyone used PlayN for developing  application other than games,
Is there support for normal GWT Widgets(because PlayN uses GWT Compiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can implement all you want with abilities like: touch/pointer, drawing, sound an so on. No, widgets are not supported from the box, but you can try to use it externally (in that case it will be supported only by brouser platform).